# how to retrieve all the values from the selected checkboxes in a checkboxlist in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist for e.g. say 5 checkboxes having values 1,2,3,4 and 5 resp. I am selecting multiple checkboxes and I want to retrieve their values in the code behind. And then i want to concatenate their values with a ',' sign and store it in a string. For e.g.

**If I select first,third and fifth checkbox then the final string should be 1,3,5**

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string values = string.Join(",", checkboxlist.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                                             .Where(i => i.Selected)
                                             .Select(i => i.Value));
```